# Capistrano for Django

Tags: django, deployment, capistrano

Does anyone know of a good Django equivalent of Capistrano/Webistrano?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Fabric](http://fabfile.org) is a Python-based application deployment system.  It can be used to deploy Django projects.

Comment: Has someone written a Websitrano style web interface for Fabric? I'm looking for something to allow users with less technical skills to deploy or redeploy.

Comment: The link to the latest version at any time is is [fabfile.org](http://fabfile.org)

Comment: I would not recommend Fabric any longer, because of author rewriting the tool almost completely between major versions.

Answer (score 13):

Capistrano (and therefore Webistrano) can be used for pretty much any deployment, so long as you use SSH. Capistrano is Rails-ready out-of-the-box but it can easily be configured to deploy PHP, Django, Java...whatever really.

Capistrano is a Ruby application so you'll need to have Ruby (and the required Gems) installed to run it.

Webistrano is a Rails application and you can run this locally or deploy it to a server if you wish.

Comment: Exactly.  We use Capistrano to deploy our PHP projects.

Comment: @feoh can you share the doc or something to deploy php projects using capistrano. I'm new to deployments.

Comment: @Pbms It's been a while since I wrote this response. In fact, it's been 6 years! These days I'd recommend using Fabric instead. It's a more general purpose tool. Capistrano has hooks for Rails applications which would be useless for you, and Fabric is also useful for much much more. Note that tcarobruce suggested the same thing in a previous answer (Which I just upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

I googled around for a simple formula, and then created my own at:  http://www.sandelman.ca/mcr/blog/ruby-on-rails/deploying_django_applications_with_capistrano/

Comment: getting 404 Not Found